# Spatial auto correlation in date line

Tags: python-3.x, geospatial, pysal

Currently, I'm calculating spatial autocorrelation.

The question is that, when calculating local spatial autocorrelation with pysal in python, is this calculation has no problem in dateline?

my data is distributed from -180/180

and the code I used to get spatial autocorrelation is below;

```
    import esda
    import libpysal.weights as lp

    wq =  lp.Rook.from_dataframe(result)
    wq.transform = 'r'
    y = result['consumption']

    li = esda.moran.Moran_Local(y, wq)
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question fully. You have radial data where -179 and 179 are almost the same thing, right? And you are afraid that `esda` will see them as very different? I am afraid that it is true, I am not aware of a way how to tell `esda` that it is the same thing. So the result will be misleading probably.